# Solidity concatenate uint into a string?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, string

How would I concatenate an integer into a string using solidity?

For instance, say I have the following:

```
uint myInteger = 12
```

How can I create the following string `"My integer is: 12"` with 12 being the value of myInteger.

In other words have, `"My integer is: " + myInteger`

Comment: Related, and possibly the solution: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/729/87

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract TestIntToString {

    string public result;

    function TestIntToString() {
        // result = uintToString(12345678901234567890);
        result = appendUintToString("My integer is: ", 1234567890);
    }

    function uintToString(uint v) constant returns (string str) {
        uint maxlength = 100;
        bytes memory reversed = new bytes(maxlength);
        uint i = 0;
        while (v != 0) {
            uint remainder = v % 10;
            v = v / 10;
            reversed[i++] = byte(48 + remainder);
        }
        bytes memory s = new bytes(i);
        for (uint j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            s[j] = reversed[i - 1 - j];
        }
        str = string(s);
    }

    function appendUintToString(string inStr, uint v) constant returns (string str) {
        uint maxlength = 100;
        bytes memory reversed = new bytes(maxlength);
        uint i = 0;
        while (v != 0) {
            uint remainder = v % 10;
            v = v / 10;
            reversed[i++] = byte(48 + remainder);
        }
        bytes memory inStrb = bytes(inStr);
        bytes memory s = new bytes(inStrb.length + i);
        uint j;
        for (j = 0; j < inStrb.length; j++) {
            s[j] = inStrb[j];
        }
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            s[j + inStrb.length] = reversed[i - 1 - j];
        }
        str = string(s);
    }
}
```

Here is the Browser Solidity screen showing the workings of this algorithm:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason maxlength is 100 and not 78?  The maximum number of digits possible with uint256 is 78.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.Remix throws an error saying `explicit conversion from uint256 to bytes1 is unsupported` for the line `reversed[i++] = byte(48 + remainder)`

Comment: for conversion issue, use   `byte(uint8(48 + remainder))`

Comment: This code is not working because type mismatch   ****reversed[i++] = byte(48 + remainder)****

Answer (score 9):

This is my first answer here :)

1. You can use openzeppelin's [Strings.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.1/contracts/utils/Strings.sol), and use **toString(value)** method to convert a number to a string.

> **toString(value)**: Converts a uint256 to its ASCII string decimal representation.

2. Now to concat, we can use **string.concat()** [available after solidity version 0.8.12].

it'll look like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract NumToStr {
    
    function testConcat(uint256 num1) public pure returns (string memory) {
        return string.concat("The number is: ",Strings.toString(num1), ", Cool!!");
    }
}
```

there are other methods in openzeppelin's [Strings.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.1/contracts/utils/Strings.sol) like:

```
toHexString(value)

toHexString(value, length)

toHexString(addr)
```

- You can read more about the **Strings** library in openzeppelin's docs [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#Strings):
- Instead of **string.concat()** we can also use **abi.encodePacked(str1, str2)**, which returns **bytes** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57531586)). Then we can typecast the **bytes** to string with **string(bytesVal)**:

```
function testConcat(uint256 num1) public pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked("The number is: ",Strings.toString(num1), ", Cool!!"));
    }
```

But, I know this approach is kinda hacky.

Comment: I have tried your approach (which I think is the simplest one) but for some reason is throwing me the following error:

"TypeError: Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory."

I'm using the Solidity compiler v8.9

Answer (score -2):

```
function strConcat(string _a, string _b, string _c, string _d, string _e) internal returns (string){
    bytes memory _ba = bytes(_a);
    bytes memory _bb = bytes(_b);
    bytes memory _bc = bytes(_c);
    bytes memory _bd = bytes(_d);
    bytes memory _be = bytes(_e);
    string memory abcde = new string(_ba.length + _bb.length + _bc.length + _bd.length + _be.length);
    bytes memory babcde = bytes(abcde);
    uint k = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < _ba.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _ba[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _bb.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bb[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _bc.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bc[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _bd.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bd[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _be.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _be[i];
    return string(babcde);
}

function strConcat(string _a, string _b, string _c, string _d) internal returns (string) {
    return strConcat(_a, _b, _c, _d, "");
}

function strConcat(string _a, string _b, string _c) internal returns (string) {
    return strConcat(_a, _b, _c, "", "");
}

function strConcat(string _a, string _b) internal returns (string) {
    return strConcat(_a, _b, "", "", "");
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses how to convert integer to a string

Comment: Isn't this just a copy of the answer from the suggested duplicate thread? In which case you should also flag the question as a duplicate.