# Parsing String to Integer for very large numbers

Tags: solidity

I've been trying to find a way to pass integer as string using a few of the function provided by the community but , while it works for " small " numbers it doesn't for larger ones.

Does anybody knows why and what is the limit here ?

```
contract Test {

    function stringToUint(string s) constant returns (uint) {
    bytes memory b = bytes(s);
    uint result = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { // c = b[i] was not needed
        if (b[i] >= 48 && b[i] <= 57) {
            result = result * 10 + (uint(b[i]) - 48); // bytes and int are not compatible with the operator -.
        }
    }
    return result; // this was missing
    }

        // parseInt
    function parseInt(string _a)  returns (uint) {
        return parseInt(_a, 0);
    }

    // parseInt(parseFloat*10^_b)
    function parseInt(string _a, uint _b) internal returns (uint) {
        bytes memory bresult = bytes(_a);
        uint mint = 0;
        bool decimals = false;
        for (uint i=0; i<bresult.length; i++){
            if ((bresult[i] >= 48)&&(bresult[i] <= 57)){
                if (decimals){
                   if (_b == 0) break;
                    else _b--;
                }
                mint *= 10;
                mint += uint(bresult[i]) - 48;
            } else if (bresult[i] == 46) decimals = true;
        }
        if (_b > 0) mint *= 10**_b;
        return mint;
    }

}
```

The first function stringToUint is from this SO ( [How to convert string to int](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10932/how-to-convert-string-to-int) )
And the second one is from the OraclizeitAPI contract.

Both don't behave as i expect for this param :

`"10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"`

Will return :

`79381376136047024986163664703589883750854290615248988403587492614211165487105`

When i'm expecting

`10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
uint result = 0;
```

The uint type can hold up to 2^256 - 1.  In decimal, this is

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
```

Note that this is less than double the result you get, which confirms that you've reached the 256 bit limit:

```
 79381376136047024986163664703589883750854290615248988403587492614211165487105
```

Your test number is actually 273 bits wide.

If you need to handle integers larger than 256 bits then you're going to have to define some sort of `bigInteger` type to handle them. I'm not aware of a generic bigInt library for Solidity; you may need to roll your own.