# Expected primary expression error in pragma solidity ^0.8.0

Tags: solidity

I am trying to use any of the uint to string function implementations from the below links.

[How to convert uint to string in solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129173/how-to-convert-uint-to-string-in-solidity)

[How to convert string to int](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10932/how-to-convert-string-to-int)

[Conversion of uint to string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6591/conversion-of-uint-to-string)

However in **pragma solidity ^0.8.0** the compiler show the following error:

**ParserError: Expected primary expression.**

Is there a workaround?

This implementation for example produces that error

```
function uintToString(uint v) public returns (string memory) {
    uint maxlength = 100;
    bytes memory reversed = new bytes(maxlength);
    uint i = 0;
    while (v != 0) {
        uint remainder = v % 10;
        v = v / 10;
        reversed[i++] = byte(48 + remainder);
    }
    bytes memory s = new bytes(i); // i + 1 is inefficient
    for (uint j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        s[j] = reversed[i - j - 1]; // to avoid the off-by-one error
    }
    string memory str = string(s);  // memory isn't implicitly convertible to storage
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your contract code.

Comment: HI @Morten, I updated the description with an example that show that error on remix compiler ^0.8.0

Comment: reversed[i++] = bytes1(bytes32(48 + remainder));

Comment: Hey @MadJackal I tried your suggestion and the error got removed! However after executing the code the end result of the function for any number is  "string: \u0000" where the correct for a uint 1 should be "string: 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a `uint256` to `bytes1` directly, but if you convert it to `uint8` first it works:

```
reversed[i++] = bytes1(uint8(48 + remainder));
```

So the full code looks like this:

```
function uintToString(uint v) public pure returns (string memory) {
    uint maxlength = 100;
    bytes memory reversed = new bytes(maxlength);
    uint i = 0;
    while (v != 0) {
        uint remainder = v % 10;
        v = v / 10;
        reversed[i++] = bytes1(uint8(48 + remainder));
    }
    bytes memory s = new bytes(i); // i + 1 is inefficient
    for (uint j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        s[j] = reversed[i - j - 1]; // to avoid the off-by-one error
    }
    string memory str = string(s);  // memory isn't implicitly convertible to storage
    return str;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the suggestion.