# How to combine string and uint as one parameter in solidity

Tags: solidity

I want to be able to input 7 seconds or 300 days in a timelock smart contract after deploying the contract.

I don't want to hard code the time frame before deploying the contract.

Here's the code:

```
contract Timelock {
mapping(address => uint) balance;
mapping(address => uint) timelock;

function(uint string _time //not working) public payable {
  balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  timelock[meg.sender] = block.timestamp + _time

}

}
```

How do I input a parameter that will take both a uint and a string as one parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Solidity is a statically typed language, and the type of each variable needs to be specified, so the type can't be dynamic.

`block.timestamp` is a `uint` value in seconds since unix epoch, so the type of the argument should be `uint`, otherwise the calculation `block.timestamp + _time` will fail

```
function(uint _time) public payable {
  balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  timelock[meg.sender] = block.timestamp + _time
}
```

In order to call this function successfully, any `string` value can be converted into `uint256` value in ethers JS and input as argument in that function call

If you want to concatenate `string` and `unit` in solidity, you can reference [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/solidity-concatenate-uint-into-a-string)