# Using a variable in an encrypted Oraclize nested query?

Tags: solidity, oracles

I have the following Oraclize query which works (generates a random number between 1 and 5, with the API key encrypted):

```
oraclize_query(1, "nested", "[URL] ['json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random.data.0', '\\n{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"generateIntegers\",\"params\":{\"apiKey\":\"${[decrypt] BA3g1TNRkJ0lqv18s+v3chf2FoZEzUXuyhOUWCcoBDKrmv51clDqUvw36lLEDJizgDrCyX7GREX7YVOfctHAT/lhLiTZNQFNjw11mq/y9mJ2gXKWw+EP/13AUnvvtDcjLek7KaBsYxk2qYuKn78Nt+EAasij}\",\"n\":1,\"min\":1,\"max\":5,\"replacement\":true${[identity] \"}\"},\"id\":1${[identity] \"}\"}']");
```

If I have a uint `number` variable, I want to be able to use this in the above query (as the 'max' value). Per [Simplest way to use a variable in an Oraclize query?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28641/simplest-way-to-use-a-variable-in-an-oraclize-query) this is done with the `strConcat` and `uint2str` functions in the Oraclize contract. I got this working when the `oraclize_query` isn't nested and the API key isn't encrypted, but can't seem to get it working with the above nested query with the API key encrypted.

This is what I've tried:

```
string string1 = '\\n{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"generateIntegers\",\"params\":{\"apiKey\":\"${[decrypt] BA3g1TNRkJ0lqv18s+v3chf2FoZEzUXuyhOUWCcoBDKrmv51clDqUvw36lLEDJizgDrCyX7GREX7YVOfctHAT/lhLiTZNQFNjw11mq/y9mJ2gXKWw+EP/13AUnvvtDcjLek7KaBsYxk2qYuKn78Nt+EAasij}\",\"n\":1,\"min\":1,\"max\":';

uint number = 5;

string string3 = ',\"replacement\":true${[identity] \"}\"},\"id\":1${[identity] \"}\"}';

oraclize_query(1, "nested", "[URL] ['json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random.data.0', strConcat(string1, uint2str(number), string3)]");
```

When testing this I'm using a new encrypted API key each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strConcat shouldn't be included inside the query string. It is a Solidity function. The correct way is the following one:

```
    string memory string1 = "[URL] ['json(https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke).result.random', '\\n{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"generateIntegers\",\"params\":{\"apiKey\":${[decrypt] BP/GT8fDh+lRNPRE4RWT/86Hcypys4kfapOzLwEHs56g4HrWhISOEKm+oKQy96i5rQnv2+mGbHNNTywqWslefgoRaYVFqXUB6cjEpKCK5XfZrDStmpftxmuO/Ekhqjj3cltH5BxYUO/PUIBzkpRECDTXP0ByjaM=},\"n\":1,\"min\":0,\"max\":";

    string memory string2 = uint2str(100);

    string memory string3 = ",\"replacement\":true,\"base\":10${[identity] \"}\"},\"id\":1${[identity] \"}\"}']";

    string memory query = strConcat(string1, string2, string3);

    bytes32 rngId = oraclize_query("nested", query);
```

Due to the way the engine decrypts and parses the strings, you need to encrypt your API key in the following way:

```
    "\"YOUR_API_KEY\""
```

Comment: this works but it should be "result.random.data.0" with a random.org query not "result.random"