# library modifying string vs string literal

Tags: solidity, string, library

I have a library which has the following function:

```
function strConcat(
    string memory _a,
    string memory _b
)
    internal pure
    returns (string memory)
```

My contract implements the library and uses the following:

```
using StringConverter for *;
...
uint minLevel = getStorageUint(
    r,
    ("_conf_").strConcat(pSetting),
    pSettingIndex,
    0
);
```

This is working, but if I change:

```
using StringConverter for string;
```

I can see the error:

```
TypeError: Member "strConcat" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in literal_string "_conf_".
        ("_conf_").strConcat(pSetting),
```

What can I type at using to make it working correctly?

Comment: Can you try with `for bytes32`

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately, no effect, same error.

Comment: Can you link the library you are using?

Comment: Sure, but library is working perfectly, the problem is with using. Took it from here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/729/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-solidity

It's kinda outdated, so you have to change string to string memory everywhere and i to uint i in loops (just tested on remix).

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

First declare string variable:

```
string memory myVariable = "_conf_";
```

Then execute the concat.

```
myVariable.strConcat(pSetting);
```

I hope this works.

The problem you have comes arises, because

```
("_conf_").strConcat(pSetting)
```

doesn't explicitly create `"_conf_"` as a `memory string`.

Comment: This solves the problem but, to be honest, it's an ugly solution and probably more gas expensive. There must be a better way... Btw. It's not me who gave you minus.

Comment: Good to know. I update my answer. Maybe you try with this one: `using StringConverter for bytes;`

Comment: Bytes didn't help either. :( I'm wondering what type does represent syntax ("anything"). It says it's literal_string but there isn't so much to read about it in solidity documentation, also can't put that at "using".

Comment: If you are just after keeping gas at a minimum you are best off sticking with `for *`. In my opinion it doesn't hurt that much.