# Can a smart contract automatically generate tokenURI based on tokenID

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens, erc-721

Is there a way a smart contract can automatically generate tokenURI using the tokenIDs of erc721 tokens, if we dont want to use other methods. I am a newbie so need some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as you have the functions `_mint()` & `_setTokenURI()`.

Following is a simple example, which is intended to do the same:

### Solidity

```
// contracts/GameItem.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity <0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract GameItem is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    string private tempURI;

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        string memory _tempURI
    ) ERC721(name, symbol) {
        tempURI = _tempURI;
    }

    function awardItem(address player) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(
            newItemId,
            string(abi.encodePacked(tempURI, uintToString(newItemId)))
        );

        return newItemId;
    }

    function uintToString(uint256 v) internal pure returns (string memory str) {
        uint256 maxlength = 100;
        bytes memory reversed = new bytes(maxlength);
        uint256 i = 0;
        while (v != 0) {
            uint256 remainder = v % 10;
            v = v / 10;
            reversed[i++] = bytes1(uint8(48 + remainder));
        }
        bytes memory s = new bytes(i);
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            s[j] = reversed[i - 1 - j];
        }
        str = string(s);
    }
}
```

### Truffle test

```
const GameItem = artifacts.require("GameItem");

contract("Redroad", async (addresses) => {
  const [admin, _] = addresses;

  it("works correctly.", async () => {
    let id = [];
    const gItem = await GameItem.new(
      "Invincible Collectible",
      "ICB",
      "http://www.myserver.com/tokenId="
    );

    await gItem.awardItem(admin);
    await gItem.awardItem(admin);

    console.log(await gItem.tokenURI("1"));
    console.log(await gItem.tokenURI("2"));
  });
});
```

Following is the output for the `truffle test`:

```
 Contract: GameItem
http://www.myserver.com/tokenId=1
http://www.myserver.com/tokenId=2
    ✓ works correctly. (229ms)
```

References take from:

- [How to concatenate strings in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/729/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-solidity)
- [How to convert uint to string in solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129173/how-to-convert-uint-to-string-in-solidity)