# bytes and uint concatenation returns \u0004 instead it should show 4 only? What is the problem?

Tags: solidity, remix, string

I am trying to concatenate byte and uint in my project. I am using the following logic I found somewhere:

```
bytes data = abi.encodePacked("Gold_",Gold);
```

where Gold contains a uint8 number. The output of above line is: Gold_\u0004, where it should be: Gold_4

Anyone please tell me what is the issue? or Any other method that I should use to concatenate the string and uint8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you're trying to do (probably a better way than all this concatenation in solidity), but I'd probably convert the uint to a string and then concatenate the strings:

Uint to string methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129173/how-to-convert-uint-to-string-in-solidity

concat strings: [How to concatenate strings in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/729/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-solidity)

Comment: Yes, Waited for the answer to this question and then Followed the above solution already.
Accepting this Answer. Thanks!