# How to use use dynamic values in reuqire statement?

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets

consider this as an smart contract which check your eligiblity and i am creating multiple instances of the contract. require validation is done. but how can i make that minimum age value dynamic in the require statement. If user passed 30 age as minimum then in require error it should be "Minimum age should be 30 years". i dont want to hardcode that minimum age in reuqire, how can i achieve that?

```
contract checkMyEligibility {
    uint requiredAge;

    constructor(uint _requiredAge) {
        requiredAge = _requiredAge;
    }

    function checkAge(uint _age) public view {
        require(_age > requiredAge, "Minimum age should be 20 years");
        /*
        // like below line.
        require(_age > requiredAge,"Minimum age should be ${requiredAge} years");
        */
    } 
}
```

Comment: You want to make it so that:"Minimum age should be 20 years" 
Could change to: "Minimum age should be 30 years" To modify the message based on the requiredAge variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate strings in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/729/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-solidity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add parameters to the error message you have to use custom errors. For a detailed explanation [see this post on Solidity Blog](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors).

Basically you can add a custom error like this:

```
contract checkMyEligibility {
    error Underaged(uint256 givenAge, uint256 requiredAge);

    uint requiredAge;

    constructor(uint _requiredAge) {
       requiredAge = _requiredAge;
    }

    function checkAge(uint _age) public view {
      if (_age < requiredAge){
         revert Underaged({
             givenAge: _age,
             requiredAge: requiredAge
          });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look in Solidity Documentation.

> It is currently not possible to use custom errors in combination with
> require. Please use if (!condition) revert CustomError(); instead.

[You can read more about it here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions):