# How to concatenate 2 strings in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, code

Question in the title, how to concatenate 2 strings in Solidity?

Googled and searched here but no luck.

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With solidity 0.8.12 you can just do string.concat like so:

```
   function strConcat(string memory one, string memory two) external returns(string memory) {
        return  string.concat(one, two);
    }
```

Also, see this: [How to concatenate strings in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/729/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-solidity)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Python is turning in its grave!

Comment: Thanks a lot kind stranger! You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

strings can concatenated by

```
abi.encodePacked(firstString, secondString)
```

ERC721 uses above concatenation method.

```
function strConcat(string calldata firstString, string calldata secondString) external pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(firstString, secondString));
    }
```